# Angular Service best practice

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I have few functions that I use in different Components of different modules. I found the solution already of using a service where I can define them and inject it later in components. However is that a best-practice for Angular 2+ ?
and where that Service must be if so ?
Otherwise what's the best practice to define same functions in one central place.

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the tour of heroes from angular? https://angular.io/tutorial Here that's explained for the basics.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to not replicate the same code in multiple places.
Define all your services, related to a component in a sub-folder named **services** and declare them **injectable**

*some.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

// ... Some code

}
```

Then you can use them by **injection** in your components which need them

*some.component.ts:*

```
import { SomeService } from '../services/some.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-some',
    templateUrl: './some.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some.component.css'],
})
export class SomeComponent {

    // Inject service in controller
    constructor(
    private service: SomeService,
    ) { }
}
```

If you have generic services (related to multiple components), declare them in a sub-folder named "services", of a general folder named **core**. In the same manner, this core folder contains a sub-folder name **components** for generic components.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services the components must provide functionality to the user and must delegate the logic to the services. Angular distinguishes service components to increase the reusability and modularity of the system however it does not enforce these principles.